# Scale columns of a data.table to unit interval

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with a mixture of numeric and factor data, such as:

```
R> dat
           x           z y w 
 1: 3.307590 -1.66951137 b a               
 2: 1.809447  4.10331322 b b               
 3: 3.314621  3.69436879 a a               
 4: 1.896529 -0.08143017 c b               
 5: 3.317341  1.01839533 c a               
 6: 1.806456 -2.09547272 a b               
...
```

I need to scale each of the numeric variables (x and z) to the unit interval. I store their minima and maxima in a separate matrix (the maximum is not simply max(x)). The first row is the min of each numeric variable, the second row is the max.

```
> cts.mat
     x  z
[1,] 1 -3
[2,] 4  5
```

How can I scale the x and z columns using the bounds in the matrix?

I tried something like

```
dat[, lapply(.SD, range01, cts.mat), .SDcol = c("x", "z")]
```

where `range01` is the function

```
range01 <- function(x, cts.mat) {
  x.as.string <- deparse(substitute(x))
  # This is (x-lower)/(upper-lower)
  (x - cts.mat[, x.as.string][1]) / (cts.mat[, x.as.string][2] - cts.mat[, x.as.string][1])
}
```

But this does not work. I think my core problem is that I don't know how to run an `lapply` with arguments that change for each column of `dat`. The changing arguments in this case are the min and max of each numeric column.

thanks for any help.

Comment: That's a good direction, but I think I need to use the bounds in `cts.mat` to change the `from=` argument of the `rescale` function. The tricky part for me is that the bounds change for each column. (the comment I replied to is deleted)

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way to do it with a loop, which I think is good enough. If anyone knows how to do it with a data.table `lapply`, I'm still interested in a solution.

```
cts.names <- c("x", "z")

for (var in cts.names) {
  dat[, (var) := scales::rescale(get(var),
                                 from = c(0, 1),
                                 to = cts.mat[, var])]
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good way to do that. Another loop option is to [use set](http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/#fast-looping-with-set)

Comment: Good idea! I forgot about `set`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very surprised by the `lapply` performance boost:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
set_loop={
  for (var in colnames(cts.mat)) {
    set(dat,j=var,value=scales::rescale(dat[[var]],
                                        from = c(0, 1),
                                        to = cts.mat[, var]))}
},
dt_loop={
  for (var in colnames(cts.mat)) {
    dat[, c(var) := scales::rescale(dat[[var]],
                                  from = c(0, 1),
                                  to = cts.mat[, var])]
}},
lapply={
  lapply(colnames(cts.mat),
         function(var) set(dat,j=var,value=scales::rescale(dat[[var]],
                                    from = c(0, 1),
                                    to = cts.mat[, var])))})

# Unit: microseconds
#     expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
# set_loop 2342.9 2380.90 2523.414 2437.15 2531.30  4856.3   100
#  dt_loop 3109.0 3176.40 4000.359 3247.70 3383.35 64652.8   100
#   lapply   65.8   74.85  103.510   83.85   90.00  2100.3   100
```

I verified that the results are the same with the three methods, interested if there is an explanation for this. Perhaps try ou with bigger data sets?

```r
library(data.table)
dat <- read.table(text='x           z y w 
1: 3.307590 -1.66951137 b a               
 2: 1.809447  4.10331322 b b               
 3: 3.314621  3.69436879 a a               
 4: 1.896529 -0.08143017 c b               
 5: 3.317341  1.01839533 c a               
 6: 1.806456 -2.09547272 a b ',header=T)
setDT(dat)


cts.mat <- read.table(text='
x  z
1: 1 -3
2: 4  5', header=T)
cts.mat <- as.matrix(cts.mat)

dat.ref <- copy(dat)

dat <- copy(dat.ref)

# set + loop
for (var in colnames(cts.mat)) {
    set(dat,j=var,value=scales::rescale(dat[[var]],
                                        from = c(0, 1),
                                        to = cts.mat[, var]))}
result.set.loop <- copy(dat)

# dt + loop
dat <- copy(dat.ref)

for (var in colnames(cts.mat)) {
    dat[, c(var) := scales::rescale(dat[[var]],
                                    from = c(0, 1),
                                    to = cts.mat[, var])]
}

result.dt.loop <- copy(dat)

# set + lapply  
dat <- copy(dat.ref)
lapply(colnames(cts.mat),function(var) set(dat,j=var,value=scales::rescale(dat[[var]],
                                                                             from = c(0, 1),
                                                                             to = cts.mat[, var])))
#> [[1]]
#>            x          z y w
#> 1: 10.922770 -16.356091 b a
#> 2:  6.428341  29.826506 b b
#> 3: 10.943863  26.554950 a a
#> 4:  6.689587  -3.651441 c b
#> 5: 10.952023   5.147163 c a
#> 6:  6.419368 -19.763782 a b
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>            x          z y w
#> 1: 10.922770 -16.356091 b a
#> 2:  6.428341  29.826506 b b
#> 3: 10.943863  26.554950 a a
#> 4:  6.689587  -3.651441 c b
#> 5: 10.952023   5.147163 c a
#> 6:  6.419368 -19.763782 a b

result.set.lapply <- copy(dat)

all.equal(result.dt.loop,result.set.loop)
#> [1] TRUE
all.equal(result.set.loop,result.set.lapply)
#> [1] TRUE
```